# how to convert pandas dataframe and numpy array into dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have the following pandas dataframe which looks like,

```
       code      comp                       name  
0   A292340    디비자산운용         마이티 200커버드콜ATM레버리지   
1   A291630  키움투자자산운용         KOSEF 코스닥150선물레버리지   
2   A278240   케이비자산운용        KBSTAR 코스닥150선물레버리지   
3   A267770  미래에셋자산운용            TIGER 200선물레버리지   
4   A267490   케이비자산운용  KBSTAR 미국장기국채선물레버리지(합성 H)
```

And I like to make dictionary out of this which will look like,

```
{'20180408' :{'A292340' : {comp : 디비자산운용}, {name : 마이티 200커버드콜ATM 레버리지}}}
```

Sorry about the data which is in foreign to you, but let me please ask.
What I tried is like,

```
values = [comp, name]
names = ['comp', 'name']
tmp = {names:values for names, values in zip(names, values)}
tpm = {code:values for values in zip(*tmp)}
aaaa = {date:c for c in zip(*tpm)}
print(aaaa)
```

aaaa is what I try to get.. and date is just simple list of date, from prior to todate. but when I run this, I got the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: The dictionary you want as output isn't a dictionary, that's half dict and half list (in other words, it's a syntax error). And what's `comp` and `name`? Should those be strings like `"comp"` and `"name"`? You should also explain _how_ you get that output: Where does 20180408 come from, and why is only the first row of the dataframe included in that dict?

Comment: comp is a list(I hope) of dataset. it represent name of the company., and name is name of the ETFs. It also consists of list made with using pands and numpy. The date isn't mentioned in the dataset I showed you. because it is out in the loop. In the inner side of the loop I made those dataframe. and I like to converge with the list.

Comment: If `comp` is a list then your output is even more broken. Lists aren't hashable and can't be used as dict keys.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that...what can I do to make this to naive number or character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? First, set `"code"` column as the index. Then use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `"orient="index"`.

```
df.set_index("code").to_dict("index")

{'A267490': {'comp': '케이비자산운용', 'name': 'KBSTAR 미국장기국채선물레버리지(합성 H)'},
 'A267770': {'comp': '미래에셋자산운용', 'name': 'TIGER 200선물레버리지'},
 'A278240': {'comp': '케이비자산운용', 'name': 'KBSTAR 코스닥150선물레버리지'},
 'A291630': {'comp': '키움투자자산운용', 'name': 'KOSEF 코스닥150선물레버리지'},
 'A292340': {'comp': '디비자산운용', 'name': '마이티 200커버드콜ATM레버리지'}}
```

Using the argument `"index"` will give the layout:

```
{index -> {columnName -> valueOfTheColumn}}
```

Here since we set `code` as the index, we have

```
code -> {"comp" -> comp's value, "name" -> name's value}
'A267490': {'comp': '케이비자산운용', 'name': 'KBSTAR 미국장기국채선물레버리지(합성 H)'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does "index" mean in this context?

Comment: @HannahLee it decides the layout of the dictionary.

Comment: Can I really use the arrow in the code?? I mean, is index = {code -> {"comp" -> comp's value, "name" -> name's value}??

Comment: @HannahLee the arrow is not a real arrow. It is just a notation. It would be ":" in a dictionary. The `orient="index"
` part is just choosing how you want the dictionary to look like. There are more potential layouts that you can choose. See [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)